# Athena - Add a Row with 0 for All Columns if a Value is Not Present

Tags: sql, case, amazon-athena, presto, date-arithmetic

I am trying to write an Athena query that will create pre and post data that can be used for analysis after a marketing e-mail went out.

After the code is ran, I am getting the following results because I have no idea how to tell Athena that if a member doesn't have a transaction during a particular time period, add that row in anyway with their age and just put zero for "net_amount" and "total_transactions":

| customer_ID | age | net_amount | total_transactions | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDRF | 25 | 85.0 | 2 | Post |
| HDWSAZ | 37 | 23.98 | 1 | Pre |
| HDWSAZ | 37 | 56.34 | 2 | Post |
| OAYDI | 42 | 8.2 | 1 | Pre |
| OAYDI | 42 | 98.29 | 4 | Post |
| IUSTRA | 31 | 88.62 | 1 | Pre |
| MAHRYS | 56 | 34.16 | 2 | Pre |

As you can see, this table above does not have a pre period row for "ABCDRF" and does not have a post period row for either "IUSTRA" and "MAHRYS" but I want to add that in with zeros for the "net_amount" and "total_transactions" and the age inserted with the right value for the Period that is missing (pre or post).

The code I am using is:

```
select distinct(customer_ID) as customer_ID, age, sum(net_amount) as net_amount, sum(lineitem) as total_visits, (case 
        when trans_date >= (current_timestamp - interval '18' month) AND trans_date < (current_timestamp - interval '6' month) then 'Post'
        when trans_date >= (current_timestamp - interval '30' month) AND trans_date < (current_timestamp - interval '18' month) then 'Pre'
        else 'nope'
        end) as Period
from trans_history
where trans_date >= (current_timestamp - interval '30' month) AND trans_date < (current_timestamp - interval '6' month)
group by 1, 5
order by 1 desc;
```

What I want:

| customer_ID | age | net_amount | total_transactions | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **ABCDRF** | **25** | **0** | **0** | **Pre** |
| ABCDRF | 25 | 85.0 | 2 | Post |
| HDWSAZ | 37 | 23.98 | 1 | Pre |
| HDWSAZ | 37 | 56.34 | 2 | Post |
| OAYDI | 42 | 8.2 | 1 | Pre |
| OAYDI | 42 | 98.29 | 4 | Post |
| IUSTRA | 31 | 88.62 | 1 | Pre |
| **IUSTRA** | **31** | **0** | **0** | **Post** |
| MAHRYS | 56 | 34.16 | 2 | Pre |
| **MAHRYS** | **56** | **0** | **0** | **Post** |

Any idea how I can get these rows added in with this code in Athena? I feel like it is just something I need to add in the "case when" statement but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` expression is not sufficient here, since some customers do *not* have data for both periods.

Instead, one approach is to `cross join` the list of customers with the fixed, predefined periods in order to generate all possible combinations. *Then*, we can bring the table with a `left join`, then aggregate:

```
select c.customer_id, c.age, p.period
    coalesce(sum(net_amount), 0) as net_amount, 
    coalesce(sum(lineitem)  , 0) as total_visits
from (select distinct customer_id, age from trans_history) c
cross join (
    select 'Post' as period
        current_timestamp - interval '18' month as start_date, 
        current_timestamp - interval '6'  month as end_date
    union all
    select 'Pre', 
        current_timestamp - interval '30' month, 
        current_timestamp - interval '18' month
) p
left join trans_history t
    on  t.customer_id = c.customer_id
    and t.trans_date >= p.start_date
    and t.trans_date <  p.end_date
group by c.customer_id, c.age, p.period
```

Comment: can you help me with the green part at the bottom? Is that supposed to be commented out? Or is that just green on accident?

Comment: @MarkJalapeno: yes that’s part of the query. There was a trailing `'` on the previous line, fixed.